# Is it possible to translate an Alexa Skill into an Android app?

Tags: android, alexa-skills-kit

So, I am currently in the process of learning Android programming, after coming from web design and building Alexa Skills using JSON. My main question is as follows: Is it possible to build an android app from the code I have for my Alexa skill? I do not necessarily need the app to be voice enabled, I just need it to be able to read the output part of my skill after something like an on-click event from pushing a button in the app. One sub-question that I have would be: if it is possible to do what I've described, what would be the easiest way to go about doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the Alexa Skill literally just a JSON file? If so, that won't be nearly enough for an Android app, which is going to require a substantial amount (in comparison) of Java code to do anything.

Comment: Hi Aaron! The current iteration of my Skill is built in JSON, however per the amazon developer portal, I see that I can build it in Java. Would that be sufficient in getting me a start on the Android app version of my Skill? For reference, my Skill tells a pun when the intent is spoken. I would need the Android version to pull the puns and then either speak one out loud, or print one to the screen. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the library below create the sample application, 
https://github.com/willblaschko/AlexaAndroid

then go to playstore download the Alexa Amazon App and enable your developed skills there.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.amazon.dee.app

And you can debug your skills ....Let me know if any issues.